# what is the meaning of ''probability of eventually getting blue ball''

Tags: probability, terminology

I was solving a question of probability as Suppose an urn contains a red ball and a blue ball. A ball is drawn at
random and a ball of the same colour is added to the urn along with
the one that was drawn. This process is repeated indefinitely. I Want to know what is meaning of word ''eventually "' in the following statement ''what is the probability of eventually getting blue ball''. All i understand is that we are intrested in probability of the event in which we get blue ball first time and any number of trials are allowed. Am i correct ? (I know how to calculate  probability of the event in which we get blue ball first time and any number of trials are allowed ).

Comment: It means that at some point in the process, you draw a blue ball.  That is, you don't go on drawing red balls forever.  Any number of trials are allowed.